# iOS sort facebook friends who are using one particular application from my friend list

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend

I have one query in fetching out some particular friends from my friend list.

I had created one iOS application in which user can login via facebook. Now I want to get the list of from "my friend" list, who are using that application. Does any particular API call to fetch this particular list? Please advise me on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply fetch the Graph API by your app token :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?fields=id,name,installed
```

if one of your friend installed the same app,the result:

```
    {
      "id": "100001410850231", 
      "installed": true, 
      "name": "name"
    }
```

if not installed:

```
   {
      "id": "100002862380104", 
      "name": "name"
    }
```